# Allignment Issues - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-tablelayout

I would like one image to be aligned left and the other to be aligned right but at present the two images just meet in the middle.

Any ideas?

```
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hello_moon, parent, false);

    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.l1);
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(getActivity());
    tr.setPadding(50, 0, 50, 0);

    TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;

    ImageView imageL = new ImageView(getActivity());
    imageL.setImageResource(R.drawable.bell_dl_256);

    ImageView imageR = new ImageView(getActivity());
    imageR.setImageResource(R.drawable.bell_dr_256);
    imageR.setLayoutParams(params);

    tr.addView(imageL);
    tr.addView(imageR);
    tl.addView(tr);

    return v;
```

Comment: try to set the TableRow LayoutParams Width to set MATCH_PARENT

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would use RelativeLayout. Only if two ImageView is enough doing what you want, you can use LinearLayout which orientation property is horizontal. And last advice you can do it in xml layout.